# Why the normal trace operator for H(div;) is surjective? I think proof is wrong..

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, finite-element-method

**prerequisite:**
For $\underline{q} \in H(\operatorname{div}, \Omega)$,we can define $\left.\underline{q} \cdot \underline{n}\right|_{\Gamma} \in H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma)$  and
$$
\int_{\Gamma} \underline{q} \cdot \underline{n} v d \sigma=\int_{\Omega} \operatorname{div} \underline{q} v d x+\int_{\Omega} \underline{q} \cdot \operatorname{grad} v d x  \ \ \ \ \  \forall v\in H^{1}(\Omega)
$$

**Then in the textbook, it says :**

Lemma 2.1.2. The trace operator $\left.\underline{q} \in H(\operatorname{div} ; \Omega) \rightarrow \underline{q} \cdot \underline{n}\right|_{\Gamma} \in H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma)$ is surjective.

Proof. Let $g \in H^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\Gamma)$ be given. Then, solving in $H^{1}(\Omega)$
$$
\int_{\Omega} \operatorname{grad} \phi \cdot \operatorname{grad} v d x+\int_{\Omega} \phi v d x=\langle g, v\rangle, \forall v \in H^{1}(\Omega)
$$
and making $\underline{q}=\operatorname{grad} \phi$ implies $\left.\underline{q} \cdot n\right|_{\Gamma}=g$.

> **I think the proof is wrong...**

The first doubt is why solving in $H^{1}(\Omega)$
$$
\int_{\Omega} \operatorname{grad} \phi \cdot \operatorname{grad} v d x+\int_{\Omega} \phi v d x=\langle g, v\rangle, \forall v \in H^{1}(\Omega)
$$
instead of solving
$$
\int_{\Omega} \operatorname{div} \underline{q} v d x+\int_{\Omega} \underline{q} \cdot \operatorname{grad} v d x  = <g,v>\ \ \ \ \  \forall v\in H^{1}(\Omega)
$$
The second doubt is about the last sentence in his proof making $\underline{q}=\operatorname{grad} \phi$. Besides, we just have $\phi \in H^{1}$, why it is sufficient to illustrate $\operatorname{grad}\phi \in H(\operatorname{div},\Omega)$

Answer (score 2):

First question: because the $H^1$-problem is solvable.

Second: Take a smooth test function $v\in C_c(\Omega)$. Then $\langle g,v\rangle=0$. This implies
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla \phi \nabla v = -\int_\Omega \phi v
$$
for all $v\in C_c(\Omega)$,
which implies $div(\nabla\phi) =\phi\in L^2(\Omega)$ in the weak sense.